# C# performance analysis- how to count CPU cycles?

Tags: c#, performance, casting

Is this a valid way to do performance analysis? I want to get nanosecond accuracy and determine the performance of typecasting:

```
class PerformanceTest
{
    static double last = 0.0;
    static List<object> numericGenericData = new List<object>();
    static List<double> numericTypedData = new List<double>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double totalWithCasting = 0.0;
        double totalWithoutCasting = 0.0;
        for (double d = 0.0; d < 1000000.0; ++d)
        {
            numericGenericData.Add(d);
            numericTypedData.Add(d);
        }
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {

            stopwatch.Start();
            testWithTypecasting();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            totalWithCasting += stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;

            stopwatch.Start();
            testWithoutTypeCasting();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            totalWithoutCasting += stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Avg with typecasting = {0}", (totalWithCasting/10));
        Console.WriteLine("Avg without typecasting = {0}", (totalWithoutCasting/10));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void testWithTypecasting()
    {
        foreach (object o in numericGenericData)
        {
            last = ((double)o*(double)o)/200;
        }
    }

    static void testWithoutTypeCasting()
    {
        foreach (double d in numericTypedData)
        {
            last = (d * d)/200;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Avg with typecasting = 468872.3
Avg without typecasting = 501157.9
```

I'm a little suspicious... it looks like there is nearly no impact on the performance. Is casting really that cheap?

**Update:**

```
class PerformanceTest
{
    static double last = 0.0;
    static object[] numericGenericData = new object[100000];
    static double[] numericTypedData = new double[100000];

    static Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    static double totalWithCasting = 0.0;
    static double totalWithoutCasting = 0.0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        {
            numericGenericData[i] = (double)i;
            numericTypedData[i] = (double)i;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            stopwatch.Start();
            testWithTypecasting();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            totalWithCasting += stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
            stopwatch.Reset();

            stopwatch.Start();
            testWithoutTypeCasting();
            stopwatch.Stop();
            totalWithoutCasting += stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
            stopwatch.Reset();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Avg with typecasting = {0}", (totalWithCasting/(10.0)));
        Console.WriteLine("Avg without typecasting = {0}", (totalWithoutCasting / (10.0)));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void testWithTypecasting()
    {
        foreach (object o in numericGenericData)
        {
            last = ((double)o * (double)o) / 200;
        }
    }

    static void testWithoutTypeCasting()
    {
        foreach (double d in numericTypedData)
        {
            last = (d * d) / 200;
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Avg with typecasting = 4791
Avg without typecasting = 3303.9
```

Comment: A little side note. Maybe it doesnt need to be stated, but when you're doing this kind of testing make sure you are compiling in release mode. You wouldnt imagine the stuff that goes on behind the scenes during debugging.   Like I said, maybe it doesnt need to be stated but it might be worth mentioning.

Comment: @Dested I tried it in release and debug mode and there is no difference in the output.

Comment: Typecasting looks almost 3 times _faster_ to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Henk, You're right... my eyes were playing a trick on me! My brain could not compute the fact that typecasting is faster, does that mean that we should typecast to increase performance?

Comment: Aligning the '=' signs in the output helps.

Comment: @Lirik: No, typecasting is *not* faster. The measuring of time is incorrect. See my answer below.

Comment: @Guffa Gotcha... now I'm seeing the correct results.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that it's not typecasting that you are measuring, it's unboxing. The values are doubles all along, there is no type casting going on.

You forgot to reset the stopwatch between tests, so you are adding the accumulated time of all previous tests over and over. If you convert the ticks to actual time, you see that it adds up to much more than the time it took to run the test.

If you add a `stopwatch.Reset();` before each `stopwatch.Start();`, you get a much more reasonable result like:

```
Avg with typecasting = 41027,1
Avg without typecasting = 20594,3
```

Unboxing a value is not so expensive, it only has to check that the data type in the object is correct, then get the value. Still it's a lot more work than when the type is already known. Remember that you are also measuring the looping, calculation and assigning of the result, which is the same for both tests.

Boxing a value is more expensive than unboxing it, as that allocates an object on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

1) Yes, casting is usually (very) cheap.

2) You are not going to get nanosecond accuracy in a managed language. Or in an unmanaged language under most operating systems.

Consider

- other processes
- garbage collection
- different JITters
- different CPUs

And, your measurement includes the foreach loop, looks like 50% or more to me. Maybe 90%.

Comment: You're right, when I moved the stopwatch in the loop I saw a significant performance difference:  
Avg with typecasting = 129570.35537  
Avg without typecasting = 378055.40987

Typecasting is almost 4 times slower!

Comment: Except that,with the Sw inside the loop you are measuring Stopwatch artifacts. Are your results repeatable>

Comment: @Henk yes, I ran this app multiple times (release and debug mode) and it yields the same results.

Comment: @Henk Doh! I thought it said a a million and two hundred thousand... now that I looked at it again I noticed my eyes were playing a trick on me... IT IS FASTER!! Is that possible?!?! Should I typecast to increase performance? LOL

Comment: @Link: artifacts. Replace the List<>s with arrays and move the Sw out again.

Comment: @Henk OK with arrays and SW out again I see a small performance increase with typecasting: Avg with typecasting = 54601.7  
Avg without typecasting = 57965.6

Comment: Note that there is no casting going on in the loop, only unboxing.

Answer (score 1):

When you call Stopwatch.Start it is letting the timer continue to run from wherever it left off.  You need to call Stopwatch.Reset() to set the timers back to zero before starting again.  Personally I just use stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew() whenever I want to start a timer to avoid this sort of confusion.

Furthermore, you probably want to call both of your test methods before starting the "timing loop" so that they get a fair chance to "warm up" that piece of code and ensure that the JIT has had a chance to run to even the playing field.

When I do that on my machine, I see that testWithTypecasting runs in approximately half the time as testWithoutTypeCasting.

That being said however, the cast itself it not likely to be the most significant part of that performance penalty.  The testWithTypecasting method is operating on a list of boxed doubles which means that there is an additional level of indirection required to retrieve each value (follow a reference to the value somewhere else in memory) in addition to increasing the total amount of memory consumed.  This increases the amount of time spent on memory access and is likely to be a bigger effect than the CPU time spent "in the cast" itself.

Answer (score 0):

Look into performance counters in the System.Diagnostics namespace, When you create a new counter, you first create a category, and then specify one or more counters to be placed in it.

```
    // Create a collection of type CounterCreationDataCollection.
System.Diagnostics.CounterCreationDataCollection CounterDatas = 
   new System.Diagnostics.CounterCreationDataCollection();
// Create the counters and set their properties.
System.Diagnostics.CounterCreationData cdCounter1 = 
   new System.Diagnostics.CounterCreationData();
System.Diagnostics.CounterCreationData cdCounter2 = 
   new System.Diagnostics.CounterCreationData();
cdCounter1.CounterName = "Counter1";
cdCounter1.CounterHelp = "help string1";
cdCounter1.CounterType = System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems64;
cdCounter2.CounterName = "Counter2";
cdCounter2.CounterHelp = "help string 2";
cdCounter2.CounterType = System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterType.NumberOfItems64;
// Add both counters to the collection.
CounterDatas.Add(cdCounter1);
CounterDatas.Add(cdCounter2);
// Create the category and pass the collection to it.
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory.Create(
   "Multi Counter Category", "Category help", CounterDatas);
```

see [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5e3s61wf%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought but sometimes identical machine code can take a different number of cycles to execute depending on its alignment in memory so you might want to add a control or controls.

Answer (score 0):

Don't "do" C# myself but in C for x86-32 and later the rdtsc instruction is usually available which is much more accurate than OS ticks. More info on rdtsc can be found by searching stackoverflow. Under C it is usually available as an intrinsic or built-in function and returns the number of clock cycles (in an 8 byte - long long/__int64 - unsigned integer) since the computer was powered up. So if the CPU has a clock speed of 3 Ghz the underlying counter is incremented 3 billion times per second. Save for a few early AMD processors, all multi-core CPUs will have their counters synchronized.

If C# does not have it you might consider writing a VERY short C function to access it from C#. There is a great deal of overhead if you access the instruction through a function vs inline. The difference between two back-to-back calls to the function will be the basic measurement overhead. If you're thinking of metering your application you'll have to determine several more complex overhead values.

You might consider shutting off the CPU energy-saving mode (and restarting the PC) as it lowers the clock frequency being fed to the CPU during periods of low activity. This is since it causes the time stamp counters of the different cores to become un-synchronized.